# Why is the canonical momentum operator for a charged particle not observable in an E&M background?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, gauge-theory, canonical-conjugation

From the Wikipedia article on the momentum operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Canonical_commutation_relation) the following operator (in position representation)

> $$\hat{\bf{P}} = -i\hbar\nabla{}$$
> "is the canonical momentum, which is not gauge invariant and not a measurable physical quantity for charged particles in an electromagnetic field. In that case, the canonical momentum is not equal to the kinetic momentum."

I.e. The operator $\hat{\bf{P}}$ corresponds to the classical canonical momentum $\overrightarrow{p_{can}} = m \overrightarrow{v}+q\overrightarrow{A}$. But what is the justification of defining an operator for a quantity that is not observable? One of the postulates of quantum mechanics includes the construction of Hermitian operators that correspond to physical observables. Why doesn't $\hat{\bf{P}}$ correspond to the kinetic momentum ${\overrightarrow{p}}_{kin} = m\overrightarrow{v}$ instead?